# How to fetch a variable declared in ssjs script into client side script

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, cloudpage

I am storing the value of lookup function into a variable say " var temp;"
In ssjs script.
I want to fetch this variable in client side script.
I am using

```
Console.log(<ctrl:var name=temp /> );
```

in client side script but getting undefined as output.

Answer (score 4):

If the output of `<ctrl:var />` is a string, then you would need to wrap it in quotes to show it as such. Although in many places this is automatically done, but it is not done with this output.

So if you do `console.log("<ctrl:var name=temp />");` it should work. Also, it is lowercase `console` not uppercase `Console`. JS is case sensitive so you need to pay attention to the case of your variables and objects.

Another option is to do the following inside your SSJS:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var temp = 'whee'

Write('<script>console.log("' + temp + '")</script>');
</script>
```

Which will write the Client-side JS script to do the console log you need utilizing the SSJS var.